# Vote for only 1 candidate in the moderator election?

Tags: support, election

I was looking at the [candidates for the 2012 Community Moderator Election](https://android.stackexchange.com/election) and I only like one candidate. Is it possible to  vote only for this candidate or do I have to make a second and third choice as well before my vote counts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [The Andro Nerd said](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1179/267), you have the option of just making your 1st Choice selection and the others will be ignored. Just note that in this voting system, if your candidate "doesn't make the cut", you will have no voice at all in what other candidates will be chosen.

If you have already cast your votes, you can change them back to "no vote" by changing your choice then changing it back. Since you can have only one of each choice, if you select someone with the same choice it will remove it from the other person.

Here, this should illustrate:

Suppose you start out like this:

- Person A - 1st choice
- Person B - 2nd choice
- Person C - 3rd choice

You really just want to vote for Person A. You can do that with a couple of steps. Just change your vote(s).

1. Change one of your other choices to be your first choice. This will remove the vote from your other choice

   - Person A - no vote
   - Person B - 2nd choice
   - Person C - **1st choice**
2. Now change the other choice

   - Person A - no vote
   - Person B - **1st choice**
   - Person C - no vote
3. Finally, change back to your original 1st choice. Leave the other choices unchosen.

   - Person A - **1st choice**
   - Person B - no vote
   - Person C - no vote

Answer (score 7):

You can vote for this one person as your first choice, and it will be counted towards it.

Your other two votes will be wasted however.

Comment: PS you can alter your choice at any time until the election ends. If you have already used all three votes you can withdraw two if you vote for your favourite for 3rd, 2nd and then first. This deletes 3rd and 2nd votes from other candidates.